# Select random rows from database apart from select few MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, random

Is there possibly a way where I am able to randomly select rows from my database but override this if I want a row to be displayed.

For example, if I wanted to select 6 random rows where the username is `Bob` but there is 1 important row which I want to be displayed with the username`Bob`, how would I select 5 random rows and the one important row?

My code currently:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR email LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR first_name LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR last_name LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `UNION` clause lies in your near future.

Comment: FYI, your current code is an open door for an SQL Injection attack.